Second order nonlinear ODE with first derivative raised to negative power
Similarly to this question, I have encountered the following ODE in the context of an optimal control problem:
$$
 \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 z^2 g''(z) + \Gamma_0 [g'(z)]^\alpha + (1 + \Gamma_1 z) g'(z) - \Gamma_2 g(z)\ ,\quad z \geq -\frac{1}{\Gamma_1}\ ,
$$
where $\sigma, \Gamma_i > 0$ as well as $\alpha < 0$ are constants. The boundary conditions at the right-hand boundary are $g(-1/\Gamma_1) = 0$ and $g'(-1/\Gamma_1) = \infty$.
Extrapolating from the answer in the other post, I attempted a solution of the form $g(z) = A z^a + B z + C$ for unknown constants $A, B, C, a$, but didn't really get anywhere.
Is there a clever way to arrive at an analytic solution, or are asymptotic/numerical methods the way forward here?

No closed form in terms of standard functions. Use numerical method of solving.
